# Export multiples modules in next.config.js : next-images

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need to export more than 1 module in my next.config.js file.

Now my file is like this:

```
const nextTranslate = require("next-translate");
module.exports = { ...nextTranslate() };
```

And i need to put this too:

```
   const withImages = require('next-images')
   module.exports = withImages()
```

Comment: next-compose-plugins - https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-compose-plugins

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Configure multiple next plugins: withMDX, withBundleAnalyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67136971/1870780)? You don't necessarily need to use `next-compose-plugins`, you can simply chain the plugins calls.

Answer (score -1):

next-compose-plugins is a great way to keep your next.config.js file clean

https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-compose-plugins

example:

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const sass = require('@zeit/next-sass');

module.exports = withPlugins([
  [sass],
]);
```

As it relates to you:

```
const nextTranslate = require("next-translate");
const withImages = require("next-images");
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");

module.exports = withPlugins([
withImages,
nextTranslate
], { other configs here that aren't plugins })
```

I'm not sure about the shape of nextTranslate, but that's the gist of it.